# Actualizar Python en Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, actualizar

Tengo Anaconda instalado en un MacOS Ventura, sobre un MacBookPro con procesador Intel. He intentado actualizar la versión de Python con:

```
conda install python=3.11.0
```

Tenía instalada la versión 3.9.13 de Python. El caso es que el ordenador lleva más de 24 horas actualizando paquetes. Se ve en la terminal los mensajes de actualización cambiantes, que indican que el proceso no está bloqueado. la pregunta es ¿Es normal tanto tiempo? ¿Cuánto puede tardar?

Comment: No es conveniente actualizar la versión python de la instalación `base` de anaconda, no por lo que tarde, sino porque puede quedar inestable e inusable. Si necesitas una versión de python en concreto, crea un nuevo entorno virtual y reinstala los paquetes. Mírate cómo exportar/importar entornos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de actualizar revisa antes la documentación oficial de anaconda. En este momento Anaconda solo soporta python 3.7, 3.8, 3.9 and 3.10. Siendo python 3.9 el intérprete por defecto.

En tu caso lo mejor es cancelar la actualización y quedarse en la version de Python 3.10

Aquí tienes la documentación oficial: [anaconda doc](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html#:%7E:text=Anaconda%20supports%20Python%203.7%2C%203.8,current%20default%20is%20Python%203.9.)